# Moment generating function: why is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2} dz = 1$

Tags: probability

Problem: Z is normally distributed with mean $0$ standard deviation 1. Goal: obtain the moment generating function of Z.

So I started with $$E[e^{tz}] = M_z(t)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tz}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-z^2}{2}})dz$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\frac{z^2}{2}-tz)} dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\frac{z^2-2tz}{2})} dz$$
completing the squares in the exponent we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\frac{z^2-2tz+t^2}{2})}*e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2})}*e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} dz$$

then my notes says $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2})} dz $ where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2})} =1$ so the mgf is $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$.

Why is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2})} =1$?

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}})dx = 1$(prob. density function of a normal distribution) but no where in the problem did it mention $\mu = t$ in fact, $\mu=0$ 
how could $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(\frac{-(z-t)^2}{2})} =1$??

Comment: Put $\frac{z - t}{\sqrt{2}}$ as $x$, then your integral looks like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} exp(-x^2) dx$, this is just your old [Gaussian Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: @TenaliRaman does $exp(a+b)$ mean $e^{a+b}$

Comment: Yes. $exp(a + b)$ means $e^{a + b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu$ is just a dummy variable, that can be replaced by anything, such has $t,z,s,\triangle\ldots$ What you in fact have, namely
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(z-t)^2}{2}}
$$ is just a  normal random variable's density function with expected value $t$ and standard deviation $1$, which you integrate on the whole line.

Note that the density function of a normal random variable with expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\text{e}^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.
$$
and that $\mu,\sigma$ are dummy variables and can be replaced by anything you want, namely $t=\mu, 1=\sigma, $ or $w=\sigma$.

Comment: what does R.V. stand for?

Comment: Random variable

Comment: err... it's just no where does it say $mu = t$! the denominator fits because the problem stated that $\sigma = 1$ but its like asking me to take a leap when we replace $\mu = t$...

Comment: @user133466 I made a correction. $\mu$ isnt equal to $t$, but the integral you're left with is the integral of a normal distribution with mean $t$ and standard deviation $1$

Comment: this is easier to understand. thank you!

Comment: does this mean $\sigma$ can be, say, $w$ and we'll still get $1$ for the integral?

Comment: i thought the standard form is$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}})dx = 1$ which in our case is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(x-t)^2}{2w^2}})dx = 1$ notice: no $\sqrt{w}$ at the denominator of 2$\pi$ and $2w^2$ at exponent's denominator

Comment: Them typos, edited the question